Calculus: Partial Derivative Equivalencies
Is the following expression true? $$\frac{\frac{\partial\text{u}}{\partial\text{x}}}{\partial\text{y}}=\frac{\partial\text{u}}{\partial\text{x}\partial\text{y}}=\frac{\partial\text{u}}{\partial\text{y}\partial\text{x}}$$
Which rules do apply?
Thanks in advance!

There's a slight abuse of notation, but it is true under some assumptions.
The correct equation would read:
$$
\dfrac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}{\partial y} = 
\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x \partial y}
$$
The last equation:
$$
\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x \partial y} =
\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial y \partial x}
$$
is correct if the partial derivatives of the second order are continuous. See here.
